# how to display certain days in a month?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to make online registration as a poly at a clinic, but some poly only operate on certain days.
how to display a specific day in a month ?
and im using php for the backend

for example i give the example array below.

$array1 = ["Sunday","Wednesday","Saturday"];

$array2 = ["Monday 01-August-2022","Tuesday 02-August-2022","Wednesday 03-August-2022","Thursday 04-August-2022","Friday 05-August-2022","Saturday 06-August-2022","Sunday 07-August-2022","Monday 08-August-2022","Tuesday 09-August-2022","Wednesday 10-August-2022","Thursday 11-August-2022","Friday 12-August-2022","Saturday 13-August-2022","Sunday 14-August-2022","Monday 15-August-2022","Tuesday 16-August-2022","Wednesday 17-August-2022","Thursday 18-August-2022","Friday 19-August-2022","Saturday 20-August-2022","Sunday 21-August-2022","Monday 22-August-2022","Tuesday 23-August-2022","Wednesday 24-August-2022","Thursday 25-August-2022","Friday 26-August-2022","Saturday 27-August-2022","Sunday 28-August-2022","Monday 29-August-2022","Tuesday 30-August-2022","Wednesday 31-August-2022"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $dates = [
        "Monday 01-August-2022", "Tuesday 02-August-2022", "Wednesday 03-August-2022", "Thursday 04-August-2022", "Friday 05-August-2022",
        "Saturday 06-August-2022", "Sunday 07-August-2022", "Monday 08-August-2022",
        "Tuesday 09-August-2022", "Wednesday 10-August-2022", "Thursday 11-August-2022",
        "Friday 12-August-2022", "Saturday 13-August-2022", "Sunday 14-August-2022", "Monday 15-August-2022",
        "Tuesday 16-August-2022", "Wednesday 17-August-2022", "Thursday 18-August-2022",
        "Friday 19-August-2022", "Saturday 20-August-2022", "Sunday 21-August-2022", "Monday 22-August-2022",
        "Tuesday 23-August-2022", "Wednesday 24-August-2022", "Thursday 25-August-2022", "Friday 26-August-2022",
        "Saturday 27-August-2022", "Sunday 28-August-2022", "Monday 29-August-2022", "Tuesday 30-August-2022", "Wednesday 31-August-2022"
    ];

    $new_array = [];

    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        array_push($new_array, Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->dayName);
    }

    dd($new_array);
```

I hope it was useful (▀̿Ĺ̯▀̿ ̿).